# inserting data from a text file to textboxes and setting combobox indecies

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

so I am writing a program and trying to setup the save/open features of the program.  I have the Save feature working just fine, but can't get the open feature to work.

The issue I'm running into is pulling the data from the text file to the form to fill in the multiple fields and controls.  my example code is below

```
Imports System.IO
Main 1
    Sub openFile_Click(sender, e) handles openFile.Click
        Dim lineIndex As Integer = 12 'this is my total lines in my file
        ofdRead.ShowDialog()
        If ofdRead.FileName <> "" then
            sr = New StreamReader(ofdRead.FileName)
            For i As Integer = 0 To lineIndex -1
                 sr.ReadLine()
            Next
            txtField1.Text = sr.ReadLine
            cboBox1.SelectedIndex = sr.ReadLine
            'this continues through all fields til complete
            sr.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I keep getting an error for anything that is being returned as not being a string, and it seems as though the data is being read in reverse as well according to my error output.

Any help would be much appreciated (been searching and pouring over forums for 2 days looking for help)

Comment: You should include the *exact* error message and where you get it.

Comment: Btw, why don't you use the simpler approach: `txtField1.Text=File.ReadLines(ofdRead.FileName).Last()`?

Comment: This doesn't make sense: `cboBox1.SelectedIndex = sr.ReadLine`. ReadLine returns the current line and advances the reader to the next line. But that line is a string whereas `SelectedIndex` is an integer. Even if that compiles with option strict off(please set it ON) it makes only sense if that line contains an integer. Is that the case?

Comment: the cboBox1 saves its result in the previous method as an integer (its selected index).  When I try and pull it with the streamreader, it gives me one of the last lines written to the file (line 11 instead of line 2)

Comment: I see. Your for-loop continues the reader until the second last line in the file. After the loop you use ReadLine again to assign the last line to the textbox. But then you call it again where you are already at the end so you assign `Nothing` to the `SelectedIndex `

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tim Schmelter for your insight.  I was calling the wrong data type for the cboBox1 variable.  Here is my corrected code (without the For-Loop, turns out i didn't need it)

```
cboBox1.SelectedItem = sr.ReadLine
```

so everytime I run into something like that I just have to tell it to put it in as a string instead of an integer